# How to remove ?___from_store=fr on the url? in Magento ver. 2.2.2

Tags: magento2.2.2

How to remove ?___from_store=fr on the url?
It seems bug or missing something in magento 2.2.2
while switching to different language at frontend , it's 
showing url like ?___from_store=fr 
please help

Answer (score 1):

To resolve this issue **follow the below steps :**

1) Logged in to your **magento admin panel**

2) Go to **store ->configuration->General->web settings**

3) Change **Add Store Code to Urls** option and **set its value to No**.

4) **Click on Save and check it on frontend**